# Is it possible to get EXTERNAL_LINKS using the GWT API?

Tags: php, google-search-console

I am trying to use the code from @eyecatchup (https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-webmaster-tools-downloads) to get data via the Google Webmaster Tools API.  I am able to get "TOP_PAGES" and "TOP QUERIES" but that is it.  What I really want is "EXTERNAL_LINKS" or even "LATEST_LINKS".

```
Here is the gwtdata.php code:

<pre>
<?php
    /**
     *  PHP class for downloading CSV files from Google Webmaster Tools.
     *
     *  This class does NOT require the Zend gdata package be installed
     *  in order to run.
     *
     *  Copyright 2012 eyecatchUp UG. All Rights Reserved.
     *
     *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     *  limitations under the License.
     *
     *  @author: Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
     *  @link:   https://code.google.com/p/php-webmaster-tools-downloads/
     */

     class GWTdata
     {
        const HOST = "https://www.google.com";
        const SERVICEURI = "/webmasters/tools/";

        public $_language, $_tables, $_daterange, $_downloaded, $_skipped;
        private $_auth, $_logged_in;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->_auth = false;
            $this->_logged_in = false;
            $this->_language = "en";
            $this->_daterange = array("","");
            $this->_tables = array("TOP_PAGES", "TOP_QUERIES",
                "CRAWL_ERRORS", "CONTENT_ERRORS", "CONTENT_KEYWORDS",
                "INTERNAL_LINKS", "EXTERNAL_LINKS", "SOCIAL_ACTIVITY"
            );
            $this->_errTablesSort = array(0 => "http",
                1 => "not-found", 2 => "restricted-by-robotsTxt",
                3 => "unreachable", 4 => "timeout", 5 => "not-followed",
                "kAppErrorSoft-404s" => "soft404", "sitemap" => "in-sitemaps"
            );
            $this->_errTablesType = array(0 => "web-crawl-errors",
                1 => "mobile-wml-xhtml-errors", 2 => "mobile-chtml-errors",
                3 => "mobile-operator-errors", 4 => "news-crawl-errors"
            );
            $this->_downloaded = array();
            $this->_skipped = array();
        }

        /**
         *  Sets content language.
         *
         *  @param $str     String   Valid ISO 639-1 language code, supported by Google.
         */
            public function SetLanguage($str)
            {
                $this->_language = $str;
            }

        /**
         *  Sets features that should be downloaded.
         *
         *  @param $arr     Array   Valid array values are:
         *                          "TOP_PAGES", "TOP_QUERIES", "CRAWL_ERRORS", "CONTENT_ERRORS",
         *                          "CONTENT_KEYWORDS", "INTERNAL_LINKS", "EXTERNAL_LINKS",
         *                          "SOCIAL_ACTIVITY".
         */
            public function SetTables($arr)
            {
                if(is_array($arr) && !empty($arr) && sizeof($arr) <= 2) {
                    $valid = array("TOP_PAGES","TOP_QUERIES","CRAWL_ERRORS","CONTENT_ERRORS",
                      "CONTENT_KEYWORDS","INTERNAL_LINKS","EXTERNAL_LINKS","SOCIAL_ACTIVITY");
                    $this->_tables = array();
                    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
                        if(in_array($arr[$i], $valid)) {
                            array_push($this->_tables, $arr[$i]);
                        } else { throw new Exception("Invalid argument given."); }
                    }
                } else { throw new Exception("Invalid argument given."); }
            }

        /**
         *  Sets daterange for download data.
         *
         *  @param $arr     Array   Array containing two ISO 8601 formatted date strings.
         */
            public function SetDaterange($arr)
            {
                if(is_array($arr) && !empty($arr) && sizeof($arr) == 2) {
                    if(self::IsISO8601($arr[0]) === true &&
                      self::IsISO8601($arr[1]) === true) {
                        $this->_daterange = array(str_replace("-", "", $arr[0]),
                          str_replace("-", "", $arr[1]));
                        return true;
                    } else { throw new Exception("Invalid argument given."); }
                } else { throw new Exception("Invalid argument given."); }
            }

        /**
         *  Returns array of downloaded filenames.
         *
         *  @return  Array   Array of filenames that have been written to disk.
         */
            public function GetDownloadedFiles()
            {
                return $this->_downloaded;
            }

        /**
         *  Returns array of downloaded filenames.
         *
         *  @return  Array   Array of filenames that have been written to disk.
         */
            public function GetSkippedFiles()
            {
                return $this->_skipped;
            }

        /**
         *  Checks if client has logged into their Google account yet.
         *
         *  @return Boolean  Returns true if logged in, or false if not.
         */
            private function IsLoggedIn()
            {
                return $this->_logged_in;
            }

        /**
         *  Attempts to log into the specified Google account.
         *
         *  @param $email  String   User's Google email address.
         *  @param $pwd    String   Password for Google account.
         *  @return Boolean  Returns true when Authentication was successful,
         *                   else false.
         */
            public function LogIn($email, $pwd)
            {
                $url = self::HOST . "/accounts/ClientLogin";
                $postRequest = array(
                    'accountType' => 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
                    'Email' => $email,
                    'Passwd' => $pwd,
                    'service' => "sitemaps",
                    'source' => "Google-WMTdownloadscript-0.1-php"
                );
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postRequest);
                $output = curl_exec($ch);
                $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                if($info['http_code'] == 200) {
                    preg_match('/Auth=(.*)/', $output, $match);
                    if(isset($match[1])) {
                        $this->_auth = $match[1];
                        $this->_logged_in = true;
                        return true;
                    } else { return false; }
                } else { return false; }
            }

        /**
         *  Attempts authenticated GET Request.
         *
         *  @param $url    String   URL for the GET request.
         *  @return Mixed  Curl result as String,
         *                 or false (Boolean) when Authentication fails.
         */
            public function GetData($url)
            {
                if(self::IsLoggedIn() === true) {
                    $url = self::HOST . $url;
                    $head = array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$this->_auth,
                        "GData-Version: 2");
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    return ($info['http_code']!=200) ? false : $result;
                } else { return false; }
            }

        /**
         *  Gets all available sites from Google Webmaster Tools account.
         *
         *  @return Mixed  Array with all site URLs registered in GWT account,
         *                 or false (Boolean) if request failed.
         */
            public function GetSites()
            {
                if(self::IsLoggedIn() === true) {
                    $feed = self::GetData(self::SERVICEURI."feeds/sites/");
                    if($feed !== false) {
                        $sites = array();
                        $doc = new DOMDocument();
                        $doc->loadXML($feed);
                        foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
                            array_push($sites,
                              $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue);
                        }
                        return $sites;
                    } else { return false; }
                } else { return false; }
            }

        /**
         *  Gets the download links for an available site
         *  from the Google Webmaster Tools account.
         *
         *  @param $url    String   Site URL registered in GWT.
         *  @return Mixed  Array with keys TOP_PAGES and TOP_QUERIES,
         *                 or false (Boolean) when Authentication fails.
         */
            public function GetDownloadUrls($url)
            {
                if(self::IsLoggedIn() === true) {
                    $_url = sprintf(self::SERVICEURI."downloads-list?hl=%s&siteUrl=%s",
                      $this->_language,
                      urlencode($url));
                    $downloadList = self::GetData($_url);
                    return json_decode($downloadList, true);
                } else { return false; }
            }

        /**
         *  Downloads the file based on the given URL.
         *
         *  @param $site    String   Site URL available in GWT Account.
         *  @param $savepath  String   Optional path to save CSV to (no trailing slash!).
         */
            public function DownloadCSV($site, $savepath=".")
            {
                if(self::IsLoggedIn() === true) {
                    $downloadUrls = self::GetDownloadUrls($site);
                    $filename = parse_url($site, PHP_URL_HOST) ."-". date("Ymd-His");
                    $tables = $this->_tables;
                    foreach($tables as $table) {
                        if($table=="CRAWL_ERRORS") {
                            self::DownloadCSV_CrawlErrors($site, $savepath);
                        }
                        elseif($table=="CONTENT_ERRORS") {
                            self::DownloadCSV_XTRA($site, $savepath,
                              "html-suggestions", "\)", "CONTENT_ERRORS", "content-problems-dl");
                        }
                        elseif($table=="CONTENT_KEYWORDS") {
                            self::DownloadCSV_XTRA($site, $savepath,
                              "keywords", "\)", "CONTENT_KEYWORDS", "content-words-dl");
                        }
                        elseif($table=="INTERNAL_LINKS") {
                            self::DownloadCSV_XTRA($site, $savepath,
                              "internal-links", "\)", "INTERNAL_LINKS", "internal-links-dl");
                        }
                        elseif($table=="EXTERNAL_LINKS") {
                            self::DownloadCSV_XTRA($site, $savepath,
                              "external-links-domain", "\)", "EXTERNAL_LINKS", "external-links-domain-dl");
                        }
                        elseif($table=="SOCIAL_ACTIVITY") {
                            self::DownloadCSV_XTRA($site, $savepath,
                              "social-activity", "x26", "SOCIAL_ACTIVITY", "social-activity-dl");
                        }
                        else {
                            $finalName = "$savepath/$table-$filename.csv";
                            $finalUrl = $downloadUrls[$table] ."&prop=ALL&db=%s&de=%s&more=true";
                            $finalUrl = sprintf($finalUrl, $this->_daterange[0], $this->_daterange[1]);
                            self::SaveData($finalUrl,$finalName);
                        }
                    }
                } else { return false; }
            }

        /**
         *  Downloads "unofficial" downloads based on the given URL.
         *
         *  @param $site    String   Site URL available in GWT Account.
         *  @param $savepath  String   Optional path to save CSV to (no trailing slash!).
         */
            public function DownloadCSV_XTRA($site, $savepath=".", $tokenUri, $tokenDelimiter, $filenamePrefix, $dlUri)
            {
                if(self::IsLoggedIn() === true) {
                    $uri = self::SERVICEURI . $tokenUri . "?hl=%s&siteUrl=%s";
                    $_uri = sprintf($uri, $this->_language, $site);
                    $token = self::GetToken($_uri, $tokenDelimiter);
                    $filename = parse_url($site, PHP_URL_HOST) ."-". date("Ymd-His");
                    $finalName = "$savepath/$filenamePrefix-$filename.csv";
                    $url = self::SERVICEURI . $dlUri . "?hl=%s&siteUrl=%s&security_token=%s&prop=ALL&db=%s&de=%s&more=true";
                    $_url = sprintf($url, $this->_language, $site, $token, $this->_daterange[0], $this->_daterange[1]);
                    self::SaveData($_url,$finalName);
                } else { return false; }
            }

        /**
         *  Downloads the Crawl Errors file based on the given URL.
         *
         *  @param $site    String   Site URL available in GWT Account.
         *  @param $savepath  String   Optional: Path to save CSV to (no trailing slash!).
         *  @param $separated Boolean  Optional: If true, the method saves separated CSV files
         *                             for each error type. Default: Merge errors in one file.
         */
            public function DownloadCSV_CrawlErrors($site, $savepath=".", $separated=false)
            {
                if(self::IsLoggedIn() === true) {
                    $type_param = "we";
                    $filename = parse_url($site, PHP_URL_HOST) ."-". date("Ymd-His");
                    if($separated) {
                        foreach($this->_errTablesSort as $sortid => $sortname) {
                            foreach($this->_errTablesType as $typeid => $typename) {
                                if($typeid == 1) {
                                    $type_param = "mx";
                                } else if($typeid == 2) {
                                    $type_param = "mc";
                                } else {
                                    $type_param = "we";
                                }
                                $uri = self::SERVICEURI."crawl-errors?hl=en&siteUrl=$site&tid=$type_param";
                                $token = self::GetToken($uri,"x26");
                                $finalName = "$savepath/CRAWL_ERRORS-$typename-$sortname-$filename.csv";
                                $url = self::SERVICEURI."crawl-errors-dl?hl=%s&siteUrl=%s&security_token=%s&type=%s&sort=%s";
                                $_url = sprintf($url, $this->_language, $site, $token, $typeid, $sortid);
                                self::SaveData($_url,$finalName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $uri = self::SERVICEURI."crawl-errors?hl=en&siteUrl=$site&tid=$type_param";
                        $token = self::GetToken($uri,"x26");
                        $finalName = "$savepath/CRAWL_ERRORS-$filename.csv";
                        $url = self::SERVICEURI."crawl-errors-dl?hl=%s&siteUrl=%s&security_token=%s&type=0";
                        $_url = sprintf($url, $this->_language, $site, $token);
                        self::SaveData($_url,$finalName);
                    }
                } else { return false; }
            }

        /**
         *  Saves data to a CSV file based on the given URL.
         *
         *  @param $finalUrl   String   CSV Download URI.
         *  @param $finalName  String   Filepointer to save location.
         */
            private function SaveData($finalUrl, $finalName)
            {
                $data = self::GetData($finalUrl);
                if(strlen($data) > 1 && file_put_contents($finalName, utf8_decode($data))) {
                    array_push($this->_downloaded, realpath($finalName));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    array_push($this->_skipped, $finalName);
                    return false;
                }
            }

        /**
         *  Regular Expression to find the Security Token for a download file.
         *
         *  @param $uri        String   A Webmaster Tools Desktop Service URI.
         *  @param $delimiter  String   Trailing delimiter for the regex.
         *  @return  String    Returns a security token.
         */
            private function GetToken($uri, $delimiter)
            {
                $matches = array(); $tmp = self::get_data($uri); preg_match_all("#46security_token(.?)$delimiter#si", $tmp, $matches); return @substr($matches[1][0],3,-1);
            }

        /**
         *  Validates ISO 8601 date format.
         *
         *  @param $str      String   Valid ISO 8601 date string (eg. 2012-01-01).
         *  @return  Boolean   Returns true if string has valid format, else false.
         */
            private function IsISO8601($str)
            {
                $stamp = strtotime($str);
                return (is_numeric($stamp) && checkdate(date('m', $stamp),
                      date('d', $stamp), date('Y', $stamp))) ? true : false;
            }
     }
?>

</pre>
```

And here is the code I am using to try to extract external links:

```
<pre>
    <?php




        include 'gwtdata.php';

            try {

                    $email = "***@gmail.com";

                    $password = "***";

                    # If hardcoded, don't forget trailing slash!

                    $website = "***";

                    # Valid values are "TOP_PAGES", "TOP_QUERIES", "CRAWL_ERRORS",

                    # "CONTENT_ERRORS", "CONTENT_KEYWORDS", "INTERNAL_LINKS",

                    # "EXTERNAL_LINKS" and "SOCIAL_ACTIVITY".

                    $tables = array("EXTERNAL_LINKS");



                    $gdata = new GWTdata();

                    if($gdata->LogIn($email, $password) === true)

                    {                      

                            $gdata->SetTables($tables);

                            $gdata->DownloadCSV($website, "./csv");                  

                    }

                           $files = $gdata->GetDownloadedFiles();

                            foreach($files as $file)

                            {

                                    print "Saved $file\n</a>";

                            }           

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                    die($e->getMessage());

            }

    ?>

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the author's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16002159/624466, is the answer to your question too.

> [..] this code is neither released by Google nor makes use of an official
>   API, but is rather a custom script processing data from the web
>   interface.
>
> [..] there were some changes to the Google Webmaster Tools web
>   interface [..]. Thus,
>   it broke some functionality of the PHP class GWTdata